# How to convert Sql Datetime query into Linq

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

```
select * from Employees where DataofJoin ='2005-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

I wrote this Linq Query as

```
public JsonResult Dif() 
{
    var ss = Convert.ToDateTime("2001-01-01 00:00:00.000");
    var x = (from n in db.Employees
                where n.DataofBirth == ss
                select n).First();

    return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

But its throwing the following error:

```
"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll 
but was not handled in user code"
```

Comment: Please show us your stacktrace

Comment: What is StackTrce

Comment: Title of the question is completely misleading, nothing to do with Sql Datetime query conversion

Comment: I don't get what your code should do. You instanciate a DataTime object, make a linq quer, store the result in x and return a new JsonResult. But you never assigne the value of x to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can Understand , This issue is because of attempt to get an item from empty object.

Because you are making a call of `.First()` and there is an empty result returned by the query. So if you do **`obj.First()` of an empty object it throws exception**. Use **`obj.FirstOrDefault()` To avoid the exception.**

And if Linq is not returning the data is an issue then use Sql Profiler  to check what query is been called,or change the date filter accordingly.

**To avoid error Use -**

```
    var x = (from n in db.Employees
             where n.DataofBirth == ss
             select n).FirstOrDefault();
```

***Update***

For getting proper date, do something like this .

`var ss = new DateTime (2005,01,01,0,0,0); //use this date in linq query`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: here why sql taking Null values when i enter through sql query Like 

select * from Employees where DataofJoin ='2005-01-01 00:00:00.000' its given me Exeact ans

Comment: because interpretation of date is been changed from Linq to sql , its not as you want it to be. Let me Update the answer to help you out.